# Why does ASCII value need to be an integer when converting to Char

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When we are converting an ASCII value to a Char value, we use `Chr(Integer)`. When we are converting a Char value to an ASCII value, we use `Asc(Char)` (which returns an integer).

My question is:

Why does Char need to convert its value to Integer when the maximum ASCII value is a Byte? Why can't we use Byte instead of Integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why `Chr()` *accepts* integers:

- There simply are *encodings* that support more than a byte's worth character range.
- See documentation for `Char Chr(Integer CodeChar)`: [Strings.Chr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As for why `Asc()` *provides* an integer:

- `Asc` wants to support multibyte characters such as *controlchars*, i.E. **CR LF**
- See documentation for `Integer Asc(Char String)`: [Strings.Asc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/x9kb82hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Chr() and Asc() functions are legacy functions that came from early VB versions, back when Unicode wasn't around yet.  Versions that did **not** have a Byte type, it didn't get added until VB.NET.  So they use Integer instead, a 16-bit value back in those days.

You should *not* be using them anymore, they are only maintained to make it easy to port old VB code and have legacy behavior.  ChrW() and AscW() are the modern versions, they know how to deal with Unicode.  Where Integer is still appropriate to deal with the range of Unicode codepoints.  "Asc" in AscW is less than appropriate, the function doesn't actually convert to ASCII codes.  You get the numerical Unicode codepoint value.  But they are kinda stuck with that name.